# Well defined sum of 2 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

There are $4$ sets $A , A' , B , B'$ and $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|.$

$(|A|:=$  the cardinality of $A$).

Prove $|A'|+|B'|=|A|+|B|$ are well defined.

I know $|A'|+|B'|=|A' \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B' \times \left\{2 \right\}|,|A|+|B|=|A \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B \times \left\{2 \right\}|$

I read thousands times what is "well defined" but i really dont understand what i'm supposed to prove.

Here is my solution :

Since $|A|=|A'|,|B|=|B'|$ there are bijections :
$f: A' \to A , g: B' \to B$.

Define $$h: A'\cup B' \to A\cup B $$

$$(x,i) \mapsto \begin{cases} f(x), ~~i=1 \\g(x), ~~i=2 \end{cases}$$

$h$ is a bijection.
Is it correct ? this it what i supposed to prove ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of your proof is right while the details are not right.

*Proof.* Since $|A'|+|B'|=|A' \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B' \times \left\{2 \right\}|$ and $|A|+|B|=|A \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B \times \left\{2 \right\}|$, it suffices to show $|A'\times\left\{1 \right\}\cup B' \times \left\{2 \right\}|=|A \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B \times \left\{2 \right\}|$, i.e., construct a bijection from $A' \times\left\{1 \right\}\cup B' \times \left\{2 \right\}$ to $A \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B \times \left\{2 \right\}$. And since $|A'|=|A|$ and $|B'|=|B|$, then there are bijections $f:A'\to A$ and $g:B'\to B$. Define $h:A' \times\left\{1 \right\}\cup B' \times \left\{2 \right\}\to A \times \left\{1 \right\}\cup B \times \left\{2 \right\}$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
h((x,i))=
\begin{cases}
(f(x),1)&x\in A'\text{ and }i=1,\\
(g(x),2)&x\in B'\text{ and }i=2.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

It's easy to see $h$ is a bijection.